# Tag clean up tools

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer

I'm sorry I couldn't think of a witty title.

I've been helping a lot recently with the ongoing tag clean up and I had a couple of ideas on how how to help further and speed up the process.

Firstly, with the help of @BenN, we have got a list of deprecated tags. Ben kindly made this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/528046/deprecated-tags) to find  tags that have been marked for removal. This might be handy to collate the tags that have been forgotten about in one place.

The current list is as follows:

- [adobe](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe)
- [asus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asus)
- [background-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/background-image)
- [cisco](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cisco)
- [corruption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/corruption)
- [delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delete)
- [editor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/editor)
- [google](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google)
- [graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics)
- [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images)
- [intel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/intel)
- [linksys](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linksys)
- [netgear](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/netgear)
- [oracle](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
- [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery)
- [samsung](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/samsung)
- [upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/upgrade)

Secondly I made a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/527992/first-posts-using-deprecated-tags) to find any posts in the First Posts Review queue that have these tags against them. My reasoning being that it helps keep the queue down and we can educate the users about proper tags right away.

Sadly the output of this data is not as immediately user friendly as it could be. If you copy the ReviewID number and append it to the url [`https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/`](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts) you can jump straight to that review.

**Example**

```
https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/567231
```

I hope this helps you out and feel free to copy it to other sites if you think it would help them with their pesky tag problem. Again massive thanks to @BenN for helping with the queries and pointing me to the data.SE site in the first place.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2003 should not be in this list. It is a valid tag.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos should not be in this list. It is a valid tag.

Comment: You need to fix your query. Just finding "Do not use" in tags is bringing in false positives. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/applet is another one.

Comment: @DavidPostill You're right, those were false positives from my query. I've edited them out of this question. I probably should have noted that my query wasn't perfect by any means :)

Comment: I haven't checked the rest.

Comment: Clever idea, but the "Do not use" phrase should not be modified in the tags, themselves to eliminate false positives in this application.  Use a better search script or post-processing to eliminate false positives.

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree. (I had just thrown together the bad tag identifier, there's definitely a lot of room for improvement.) I composed [an MSE feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283802/295684) that would help greatly with this.

Comment: BTW, we do get a trickle of use of deprecated tags on new posts.  But some of them get caught just by eagle-eyed users.  During the tag cleanup, they don't add a significant workload (what's a few more when you're cleaning up hundreds).  In terms of educating users, they already see the warning when they select the tag.  If they gave a crap, they wouldn't use it in the first place.  :-)   See http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40548-never-attempt-to-teach-a-pig-to-sing-it-wastes.

Comment: "lock out / TAG out tools"?